# Database that contains timespans of cyber attacks in the web

Tags: security, data-sets, evaluation-strategies

for a project I need to evaluate a model, that tries to predict wether a certain cyber-attack (i.e. connection to a low level honeypot) is just a random access, a new attack-wave or an already known attack-wave. Therefore I am looking for a ground truth. Is there some database that contains historical attack-waves? Something like

```
September, 24 - 29: Attack to Port 8080
September, 25 - 27: Attack to Port 1234
```

In the best case it would be a database, where every hacker in the world signs-up, when he starts and ends a cyber attack ;)

Or does someone has another idea how I could evaluate such a model?

Best regards
Felix

Comment: I'm not sure whether requests for data sets are on-topic here.  Any community votes?

Comment: "Meta-information about computer science" (bibliometrics, cientometrics) may be on-topic.

Comment: Where would it be on topic? - I could move my question there.

Comment: I'd think [information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) promising.